# How can I make a glowing mushroom farm?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, the mud block seems a little useless, I read on the crappy Wikia page that Mud blocks can be used to grow mushrooms in some fashion.

From [Mud on Wikia](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Mud):

> Mud is slightly darker than normal
>   Dirt. It will sustain Underground
>   Jungle grass as well as Mushroom
>   Grass, but only at below-zero depths.
>
> The largest single source of Mud in
>   any given world is the Underground
>   Jungle.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Should I plant mud blocks next to some green growth?

Comment: Do you know you mentioned the 'Crappy Wikia' page and then linked to the 'Terraria Online' wiki instead? :)

Comment: @James: I'll change it, someone else changed the link, but not the text.  Actually I'll just change the link back, altering the question in this manner makes the question less meaningful.  Because part of the issue was that I didn't know there was a second wiki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mud is required to grow mushroom grass (which gives glowing mushrooms) and jungle grass (which mimics the underground jungle).

As long as your depth (as per a depth meter) is below "sealevel", both types of grass can be planted.

Here's an example mushroom farm:

[image: An efficient mushroom farm]

For further instruction on how to best take advantage of mushroom farms like the above, see [the wiki.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Gardening)
(For what it's worth, the wiki you linked to was not the official Terraria wiki)

Comment: @Raven Nice screenshot! A silly question maybe, is their an item that allow to jump out of that holes?

Comment: @Drake - you can see the wooden platforms, which you can land on and jump again.  If they weren't there, a grappling hook would work fine (or maybe the Red Balloon and Air in a Bottle).

Comment: @Ian Ah thank you, I am blind, didn't notice the wooden platforms.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, that can still be improved. Extending the horizontal levels by 2 or 3 blocks you will get more into the same space (the vertical lines are what block growing after all). You should even be able to remove them, after the magic blue extended onto the levels.

Comment: @kissaki - I'm not sure that would get you more mushrooms/block. More mushrooms total, sure, but I'm not sure there's an efficiency improvement. That said, I think the picture *could* be improved with taking out the center of each "+". giving a checkerboard-like appearance.

Comment: More mushrooms in the same space. Well, taking out the vertical connectors you will have a block removed, where a mushroom can grow. So the number of mushrooms per block will definitely increase.

Comment: i think the best setup is [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjipSxBxUHU), as it allows you to mow down three lanes of shrooms at once.

Comment: This is a more optimized version of the above mushroom farm. http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/5641/mushroomfarm.png